# SQL Select rows with same name but different price

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 tables `COMMODITY_New` and `COMMODITY_Old` with some rows each. I need to select rows from `COMMODITY_New` that have NAME in `COMMODITY_Old.NAME` but with a different price.

Example:

COMMODITY_New:

```
+------+------+
|Name  |Price |
+------+------+
|Apple |200   |
|Socks |100   |
+------+------+
```

COMMODITY_Old:

```
+------+------+
|Name  |Price |
+------+------+
|Apple |180   |
|Socks |100   |
+------+------+
```

New price is not always higher.

My SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    NAME, PRICE
FROM 
    COMMODITY_New
WHERE 
    COMMODITY_New.NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM somedb2.COMMODITY_Old) 
    AND COMMODITY_New.PRICE = (SELECT PRICE FROM somedb2.COMMODITY_Old)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
select n.*
from commodity_new n
where exists (select 1
              from commodity_old o
              where o.name = n.name and o.price <> n.price
             );
```

Comment: Can you explain please,what is "select 1"?

Comment: @Андрей . . . `EXISTS` only checks for the existing of a *row*.  The columns are ignored.  `1` is the easiest value to type.

Answer (score 0):

Just join the two tables by `name` and select the rows with different prices.

```
SELECT o.name, o.price, n.price 
FROM commodity_old o INNER JOIN commodity_new n ON o.name = n.name
WHERE o.price <> n.price;
```